# Absinthe.Plug not available

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

After installing absinthe_plug I'm getting the following error:

```
= Compilation error in file lib/kerrigan_api_web/router.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function KerriganApiWeb.Absinthe.Plug.init/1 is undefined (module KerriganApiWeb.Absinthe.Plug is not available)
```

Here are my deps

```
{:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0"},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.10"},
  {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
  {:poison, "~> 3.1"},
  {:absinthe, "~> 1.3.0"},
  {:absinthe_plug, "~> 1.3.0"},
  {:absinthe_ecto, git: "https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe_ecto.git"},
  {:faker, "~> 0.7"},
```

As far as I'm aware I dont need to add anything else.  I've followed the simple steps here:

[absinthe_slug](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe_plug)

EDIT:  My router

```
defmodule KerriganApiWeb.Router do
  use KerriganApiWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", KerriganApiWeb do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/hotsdata_user", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources "/battletag_toonhandle_lookup", PlayerController, except: [:new, :edit]

    forward "/graph", Absinthe.Plug, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
    forward "/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
  end

end
```

I had added require Absinthe.Plug but that didn't work

Comment: Can you post the contents of `router.ex`?

Comment: Added, see above.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're passing an `alias` (`KerriganApiWeb`) to `scope`, which prepends the alias to all modules passed to the route declaration functions inside. This converts `Absinthe.Plug` to `KerriganApiWeb.Absinthe.Plug` in the call to `forward`, which is not what you want. You want the module `Absinthe.Plug`. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Remove `alias` parameter and use `KerriganApiWeb` explicitly in all route declaration functions that need it.

   ```
   scope "/" do
     pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

     get "/", KerriganApiWeb.PageController, :index
     resources "/hotsdata_user", KerriganApiWeb.UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
     resources "/battletag_toonhandle_lookup", KerriganApiWeb.PlayerController, except: [:new, :edit]

     forward "/graph", Absinthe.Plug, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
     forward "/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
   end
   ```
2. Create a new `scope` with the same path and pipeline and declare the `forward` routes there:

   ```
   scope "/", KerriganApiWeb do
     pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

     get "/", PageController, :index
     resources "/hotsdata_user", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
     resources "/battletag_toonhandle_lookup", PlayerController, except: [:new, :edit]
   end

   scope "/" do
     forward "/graph", Absinthe.Plug, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
     forward "/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
   end
   ```

The Phoenix docs [say](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#module-scopes-and-resources) that the first one will increase the compilation time of your application. Even if that weren't the case I'd go with the second one as I find that more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move two endpoints "/graph" and "graphiql" out of scope "/".

```
defmodule KerriganApiWeb.Router do
  use KerriganApiWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", KerriganApiWeb do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/hotsdata_user", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources "/battletag_toonhandle_lookup", PlayerController, except: [:new, :edit]
  end

  forward "/graph", Absinthe.Plug, schema: KerriganApi.Schema
  forward "/graphiql", Absinthe.Plug.GraphiQL, schema: KerriganApi.Schema, interface: :advanced

end
```